# Create ECS task from AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have an EC2 instance which is currently stopped and I created an AMI from it. It has the ECS and Docker services installed and enabled to start at boot. How can I create an ECS task to clone this AMI and have the ECS service create more EC2 instances from the AMI as needed?

The ECS tasks appear to only allow me to create EC2 instances from Docker containers. Is there a way to create them from AMI images?

Comment: "The ECS tasks appear to only allow me to create EC2 instances from Docker containers." No it doesn't. You can't "create EC2 instances from Docker containers".  That entire statement makes no sense. What you are looking for is the ECS Capacity Provider https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/asg-capacity-providers.html

Comment: Upon second reading of your question, I think you are confused about what ECS is. Your question title "Create ECS task from AMI" appears to indicate a disconnect in your understanding of ECS. ECS is a container orchestration service. ECS creates and manages docker containers. It can run those docker containers on either Fargate or EC2 instances. It is really unclear from your question what you are trying to accomplish, and if ECS is even the correct tool for you to be using.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Now everything makes more sense.